# How do I get git status to display with proper symbols on fresh install of alpine OS on an oh-my-zsh prompt?

Tags: git, zsh, alpine-linux

On a fresh install, the git status line is shows: `[_master _]` instead of something like  `[±master ●●]`, showing underscores instead of the symbols.

This is on the alpine OS using the bureau theme with oh-my-zsh.

Comment: You're missing some set of fonts. The font installation question belongs on an appropriate more-specific forum.

Comment: How did you set `LANG`?

Comment: @torek I had tried installing fonts but that didn't help. Problem is hinted at by @user1934428 where `LANG` is not set for tmux.

Comment: Aha: you hadn't mentioned tmux. (I was assuming you were on the console, or ssh-ed in, or whatever.)

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice it was only happening in tmux.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this was actually a problem with tmux. Adding:

```
CHARSET=UTF-8
LANG="C.UTF-8"
```

to `/etc/profile` and reloading the shell fixed things.

Also possible to start tmux with the `-u` option: `tmux -u`. This also fixed the problem.